# How to count the number of object types in working memory in Drools

Tags: drools, rules

This is a refinement to one of the rules from this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211825/how-can-i-match-on-multiple-objects-of-the-same-kind-in-drools-5).

I'am using Drools 5.4.FINAL.   I have a rule like this which almost works, but not for all scenarios:

```
rule not_OK_1
when
  not BMSContract( status == "ACTIVE" )
then
  // there is no ACTIVE
end
```

Because I can have one or more BMSContract rules in Working Memory - I have to refine the rule above so that it fires only when there is not BMSContract (status == "ACTIVE" ) **and** there are more than one BMSContracts in working memory (regardless of their status).

In other words, I need an additional conditional expression that takes into consideration the number BMSContracts in working memory.

```
rule not_OK_1
when
  not BMSContract( status == "ACTIVE" )
  And more than one BMSContract object exists
then
  // Fail - no ACTIVE in the list
end
```

... other rules below will examine single BMSContract scenarios and decide: success or failure.

How can I write an expression that tests the number of instances of BMSContract in working memory is greater than 1?

Comment: Ok - I solved it like this:  $nbrOfContracts : Number( intValue > 1 ) from accumulate( $contract : BMSContract( ), count( $contract ))

It works - hope this is an efficient way to do it.